# Intermittent failure: WSO2-IS 5.6 fails to send email with error - "Event dropped at Output Adapter... Error in message format, null "

Tags: email, wso2, wso2-identity-server

App: WSO2-IS 5.6

I am getting the following error intermittently when trying to send email on user registration/pwd reset. Retrying later for the same email account works fine. Lack of detail in error message makes it difficult to identify the root cause. Stack trace from the log is copied below.

```
TID: [-1] [] [2022-01-13 14:27:44,459] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter} -  Event dropped at Output Adapter 'EmailPublisher' for tenant id '-1234', Error in message format, null 
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter$EmailSender.run(EmailEventAdapter.java:306)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this error is happening because the WSO2IS cannot connect with the email publisher you are using. To fix this.

1. Stop the IS server
2. Go to *<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml*
3. Check if the configurations are in place correctly

```
<transportSender  name="mailto"
    class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.from">{SENDER'S_EMAIL_ID}</parameter>
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.user">{USERNAME}</parameter>
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.password">{PASSWORD}</parameter>
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
    <parameter  name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

(If you are using a Gmail account you have to "Allow less secure apps" in your account.)
4. Restart IS server.

To check email and passwords are correct you can use the username and password here to connect with the email publisher. For more details please check the below documentation

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Configuring+Email+OTP#ConfiguringEmailOTP-ConfiguretheemailOTPprovider

Comment: I am not sure if the configuration is the issue as it is working most of the time. It fails once in a while and works later for the same email address.

Comment: Same email account means, the same email configurations from the email publisher? better check with email server configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when an outsider blocks Gmail from signing in to the account. Enabling 'Low Security Application Access' at https://myaccount.google.com/security will solve this problem.